# How to see separate losses per output neuron in keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

The output architecture is below:

```
# Iteratively construct the output layer
output_layers = []
for i in range(self.slice_train_y.shape[-1]):
    name = list(self.slice_train_y)[i]
    
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name=name)(x)
    output_layers.append(out)
    
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_layers)
```

In the training process this allows me to see the loss per output neuron, however the model is very particular then about the shape of the training data since it expects n arrays of shape `(None, 1)` so I have to pass all the data as a list of lists `[list1, list2, list3, ...]`. This is functional but there are small reason where it would be more convenient to do `Dense(n)` and view the separate losses as when using `validation_split` it does not synthesise well with that format of passing the target data. Tensorboard outputs an averaged loss as in training as well.

When using keras tuner it then skews the tuning process too as it uses validation loss as its metric to judge hyperparameter configurations.